# ¿Qué diferencia entre los métodos getCanonicalName () e getName ()?

Tags: java

Para devolver el nombre del paquete con el nombre de la clase en Java siempre he utilizado el método `getName()`. Me di cuenta de que aparentemente el método `getCanonicalName()` devuelve la misma cosa.

Ver sólo un ejemplo personalizando el método `toString()`:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.getClass().getName();
}
```

Isso aparentemente equivaleria a:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.getClass().getCanonicalName();
}
```

¿Cuál es la diferencia real entre los métodos `getCanonicalName()` y `getName()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**getName()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName--) Devuelve el nombre de la entidad (clase, interfaz, array, tipo primitivo o void) representada por este objeto de clase, como una cadena.
Este nombre se usa para cargar dinámicamente la clase usando [Class.forName()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName-java.lang.String-)

[**getCanonicalName()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getCanonicalName--) Devuelve el nombre canónico de la clase subyacente definida por la especificación de lenguaje Java. Devuelve null si la clase subyacente no tiene un nombre canónico (es decir, si es una clase local o anónima o un array cuyo tipo de componente no tiene un nombre canónico).
Es el nombre que se utilizaría en una instrucción de importación e identificaría de forma exclusiva la clase. Puede ser útil durante las operaciones de registro (Logging).

```
package com.myapp;

import java.lang.*;

public class ClaseDemo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

    ClaseDemo c = new ClaseDemo();
    Class clase = c.getClass();    
    System.out.println("Clase: " + clase.getCanonicalName()); 

   }
}
```

Obtiene como salida:

```
Clase: com.myapp.ClaseDemo
```

Considero importante agregar también:

[**getSimpleName()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSimpleName--)  Devuelve el "nombre simple" de la clase subyacente como se indica en el código fuente. Devuelve una cadena vacía si la clase subyacente es anónima. Identifica libremente la clase, puede ser útil durante las operaciones de registro (Logging), pero no se garantiza que sea único.

```
package com.myapp;

import java.lang.*;

public class ClaseDemo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

    ClaseDemo c = new ClaseDemo();
    Class clase = c.getClass();    
    System.out.println("Clase: " + clase.getSimpleName()); 

   }
}
```

Obtiene como salida:

```
Clase: ClaseDemo
```

Una diferencia importante es que si usas una clase anónima puedes obtener un valor null al tratar de obtener el nombre de la clase mediante `getCanonicalName()`

**getName()**

```
Clase: com.myapp.ClaseDemo
```

**getCanonicalName()**

```
Clase: null
```

**getSimpleName()**

```
Clase: ClaseDemo
```

Answer (score 3):

Te lo voy a explicar con un test:

```
//primitive
System.out.println(int.class.getName());
System.out.println(int.class.getCanonicalName());

System.out.println();

//class
System.out.println(String.class.getName());
System.out.println(String.class.getCanonicalName());

System.out.println();

//inner class
System.out.println(HashMap.SimpleEntry.class.getName());
System.out.println(HashMap.SimpleEntry.class.getCanonicalName());   

System.out.println();

//anonymous inner class
System.out.println(new Serializable(){}.getClass().getName());
System.out.println(new Serializable(){}.getClass().getCanonicalName());
```

Resultado:

```
int
int

java.lang.String
java.lang.String

java.util.AbstractMap$SimpleEntry
java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry

ClassnameTest$1
null
```

El resultado de mirar esto es:

El nombre es el nombre que utilizaría para cargar dinámicamente la clase con, por ejemplo, una llamada a `Class.forName` con el `ClassLoader` predeterminado.

El nombre canónico es el nombre que se utilizaría en una instrucción de importación e identificaría de forma exclusiva la clase. Puede ser útil durante las operaciones de `toString` o registro.